# WP: is possible to get uri out of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song

Tags: windows-phone, media

I have Song object returned from MediaLibrary. How do I get its uri or absolute path with file name? Any un-published API? The constructor has FromUri that used to construct Song object. Wonder if there is a way to retrieve it? It seems that GetPathFromToken from MediaLibraryExtensions. But what is the "token" that I need to come up with? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the "What is the token I need to come up with?" part of the question:
The value of Token is supplied to an application on a query string when that application is registered to extend various parts of the Windows Phone OS, this includes [Photo Share Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), [Photo Edit Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662932%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Auto Launch from a File Association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

All the examples use [GetPictureFromToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.getpicturefromtoken.aspx), but you can imagine the same scenario with other media types being 'Launched' via file association.

Here's a sample of how to use token with GetPicturesFromToken

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a dictionary of query string keys and values.
    IDictionary<string, string> queryStrings = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;

    // Ensure that there is at least one key in the query string, and check whether the "token" key is present.
    if (queryStrings.ContainsKey("token"))
    {
        // Retrieve the photo from the media library using the token passed to the app.
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        Picture photoFromLibrary = library.GetPictureFromToken(queryStrings["token"]);

        // Create a BitmapImage object and add set it as the image control source.
        BitmapImage bitmapFromPhoto = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapFromPhoto.SetSource(photoFromLibrary.GetImage());
        image1.Source = bitmapFromPhoto;
    }
}
```

[GetPathFromToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions.getpathfromtoken%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx) should behave in the same way.

As for the other parts of the question. If you are using a song object that you got a reference too via the MediaLibrary, there is no way to get the uri or path to that object via any legitimate published api's.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please share if there is other APIs that are not published to get path to song object? :)

Comment: @thsieh sorry I'm not familiar with any undocumented API's, your best bet is to search the hacker community and/or stackoverflow for these. There was a lot of progress made on undocumented APIs in Win Phone 7, but I'm not sure much has been done on Win Phone 8 because its more locked down.  Be aware that if you use any undocumented APIs your app will almost certainly fail certification and will never be able to exist in the App Store.