# Windows phone 8 convert Song to Byte array

Tags: windows-phone-8, byte, arrays, media-library

I want to convert a Song from MediaLibrary to a byte array in order to upload it. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: _what you have tried so far?_

Comment: I have searched on internet, but I haven't found a proper answer. Song class doesn't have any method to get the path nor the stream, and I would like to know if I could get the Song converted to bytes.

Comment: I have done some research and I have found that Song is not possible to extract bytes, but I am still not sure if that sentence is right. Could somebody confirm me that? If not, do you know how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It took me a day to search Google, but i still could not find what i need.

I am not sure that it can help you but let you try to read this topic.

[WP: is possible to get uri out of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247466/wp-is-possible-to-get-uri-out-of-microsoft-xna-framework-media-song)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I have seen, I think that is not possible to get the byte array of the songs stored in the Medialibrary, and this is a truly shame :(